# Serial Communication using NFC reader using java

Tags: java, serial-port, serial-communication

I have a NFC reader that comes with SDK for communication.I can use VB, VC++ or C# with the dll provided by the vendor to communicate using USB or RS232. The reader can be communicated using C/C++ over RS 232 without using the SDK. I am trying to use java for serial communication. I am able to send the command using RS 232 but I am not getting the response from the reader. For example I send one command to detect card presence. The reader should respond back with card serial number if card is present else will return some error code. But I am getting nothing. Attached here is my sample code to detect card. Just let me know if the code is correct or I need to change the approach for communication with the reader.

```
package com.pramod.serialcomm;

import gnu.io.CommPort;

import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier;

import gnu.io.SerialPort;

import gnu.io.SerialPortEvent;

import gnu.io.SerialPortEventListener;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.InputStream;

import java.io.OutputStream;`enter code here`

public class TwoWaySerialComm {
    InputStream in ;
    OutputStream out;

    void connect( String portName ) throws Exception {
        CommPortIdentifier portIdentifier = CommPortIdentifier
            .getPortIdentifier( portName );
        if( portIdentifier.isCurrentlyOwned() ) {
          System.out.println( "Error: Port is currently in use" );
        } else {
          int timeout = 2000;
          CommPort commPort = portIdentifier.open( this.getClass().getName(), timeout );
          System.out.println( "Success: Port currently in use : " + commPort );
          if( commPort instanceof SerialPort ) {
            SerialPort serialPort = ( SerialPort )commPort;
            serialPort.setSerialPortParams( 115200,
                                            SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                                            SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                                            SerialPort.PARITY_NONE );

             in = serialPort.getInputStream();
             out = serialPort.getOutputStream();

            ( new Thread( new SerialReader( in ) ) ).start();
            ( new Thread( new SerialWriter( out ) ) ).start();


          } else {
            System.out.println( "Error: Only serial ports are handled by this example." );
          }
        }
      }

      public static class SerialReader implements  SerialPortEventListener,Runnable {

        InputStream in;
        private byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        public SerialReader( InputStream in ) {
          this.in = in;
        }

        public void run() {
          byte[] buffer = new byte[ 1024 ];
          int len = -1;
          try {
            while( ( len = this.in.read( buffer ) ) > -1 ) {
              System.out.println("reading : " +  new String( buffer, 0, len ) );
            }
          } catch( IOException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }

        }

        @Override
        public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent arg0) {
            
            int data;
            try {
                int len = 0;
                while ((data = in.read()) > -1) {
                    if (data == '\n') {
                        break;
                    }
                    buffer[len++] = (byte) data;
                }
                synchronized (this){
                    System.out.println(new String(buffer, 0, len)
                    );
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(-1);
            }
        }
      }

      public static class SerialWriter implements Runnable {

        OutputStream out;

        public SerialWriter( OutputStream out ) {
          this.out = out;
        }

        public void run() {
          try {
            int c = 0;
            while( ( c = System.in.read() ) > -1 ) {
                
              this.out.write( c );
            }
          } catch( IOException e ) {
              try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
      }

      public static void main( String[] args ) {
        try {
            TwoWaySerialComm commTwo = new TwoWaySerialComm() ;
            commTwo.connect("COM10");
            String str = "4C00000100";  // Command to detect card presence by the NFC reader
            commTwo.out.write(str.getBytes());
            System.out.println("writting : " + str);
        } catch( Exception e ) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
}
```

Thanks
Pramod

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the API you are using but i think you might be doing 2 things wrong.

**1. Reading from System.in**

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#in) this is mostly used for keyboard input and so in the SerialWriter class this code

```
while( ( c = System.in.read() ) > -1 ) {                
       this.out.write( c );
}
```

Is actually waiting to read data from your keyboard but i assume you are writing data to your program using your USB device hence you might be looking for input in the wrong place. You actually need to read data from

```
serialPort.getInputStream();
```

**2. Use only 1 Thread for reading and writing**

From you sample code it looks you are creating an simple ping server hence if Problem 1 is actually true then you need to start only 1 Thread for your demo purpose which reads data from

```
serialPort.getInputStream();
```

And writes it back to

```
serialPort.getOutputStream();
```

Maybe like this

```
 public static class SerialPinger extends Thread {

    InputStream in;
    OutputStream out;

    private byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    public SerialPinger(InputStream in,OutputStream out )
    {
      this.in = in;
      this.out=out;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
      try {
        while( ( len = this.in.read( buffer ) ) > -1 ) {
          System.out.println("reading : " +  new String( buffer, 0, len ) );

         System.out.println("Writing Back");

         this.out.write(buffer,0,len);
        }
      } catch( IOException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

    }
```

And in your main method replace 2 threads

```
( new Thread( new SerialReader( in ) ) ).start();
( new Thread( new SerialWriter( out ) )).start();
```

With this

```
new SerialPinger(in,out).start();
```

Either pass in your serialPort input stream or your System.in if problem 1 is false.

Seems like you got your code from [this](https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/methods/gnu.io.SerialPort/addEventListener) link.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. Actually the objective is to send a command from the application and get response from the reader connected to serial port. Though I had used the input stream earlier, I will check it again as per your suggestion and get you back with the results.